# How to set a custom post type as home page and set post page to regular post?

Tags: child-theme

I am trying to create a child theme where I have created a custom post type i.e "art". I want to display all CPT posts to the homepage with pagination and the regular post to the post page.

Currently, I set **Your latest posts** reading settings and add an action that will show my all custom post type at home page.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_cpt_to_homepage' );

function add_cpt_to_homepage( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'art' ) );
    return $query;
}
```

But my question is, is there any way to show my regular post on a different page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to show your regular posts on a different page.

1. Create a new [page template](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress#manual)
2. Include a new `WP_Query` using `post` as the `post-type`. [Example](https://denverdata.com/blog/how-use-wpquery-display-custom-post-type)
3. On the backend, create the page you want to use to display your posts
4. In the options, select your new page template for the page
5. Your posts should appear on the new page

Comment: Thank you. Have to try